# Dynamic Linking and global variables

Tags: c, linux, dll, dynamic-linking

I'm a beginner in C and linking, just have two question on .so share library.

Lets say I have a math.so shared library that originally created from add.c and multiple.c,
and I have a program test.c that only use add function in add.c.

Q1- Even I am not using the multiple function, the whole math.so shared library(include multiple' code and data) will still be loaded in the the memory, is my understanding correct?

Q2- Since  math.so  is shared in memory, how do we deal with global data in math.so? e.g. there is a global variable number = 0 in add.c, the test.c modifies it by `number = 1` and another program test2.c modify it by number = 2, so after context switch, test.c tries to print number whose value is 2, not really the value (which should be 1) that is supposed to be for test.c?

Comment: Global data is in the program's space, so each program will have a copy of any global variables.

Answer (score 1):

> Even I am not using the multiple function, the whole math.so shared library(include multiple' code and data) will still be loaded in the the memory

Not quite correct.

The entire library will be `mmap`ed into your process. However, most modern OSes use [demand paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging), which means that code and data is not *actually* loaded into memory until accessed.

If the shared library is large (larger than one page, which is typically 4KiB or 8KiB), and only one function from that library is accessed, then it's highly likely that unused portions of the library will in fact *not* be loaded into memory.

> Since math.so is shared in memory, how do we deal with global data in math.so?

The global data is also `mmap`ed into your process, with [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) semantics.

If you have two processes, and each *reads* the value of `number` that is a global variable in `math.so`, both processes will use (share) the same actual physical page of RAM. But as soon as one of the processes *writes* to `number`, a new physical page of RAM will be allocated to that process (un-sharing the page), and update will be done only to that (now private) copy.